# Can the card Disintegrate destroy creatures with indestructible?

Tags: magic-the-gathering, mtg-indestructible

I was playing magic the gathering with my friend, and I was using the card [Zetalpa, Primal Dawn](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Zetalpa%2C%20Primal%20Dawn), which has indestructible. He wanted to play the card [Disintegrate](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Disintegrate) on the Zetalpa to destroy it, but we weren’t sure whether or not it would actually kill it.

[image: Zetalpa, Primal Dawn card image]
<sub>(source: [scryfall.com](https://img.scryfall.com/cards/normal/front/3/d/3d10560f-199d-4d04-b573-90024f8aecc4.jpg?1555039845))</sub>

Comment: Options to get rid of an indestructible creature: Have it lose indestructible, then deal damage (Burn from within, Hour of Devastation). Exile it (Vraska's Contempt). Shuffle it into its owners library or bounce it. Have the owner sacrifice it (Priest of Forgotten Gods). Reduce its toughness to 0 using -X/-X effects (Tragic Slip).

Comment: Erik's comment is helpful, but it should be noted that while cards that remove indestructible are quite rare (and the example cards listed are almost exhaustive), there's plenty of options for both exiling or reducing toughness of creatures, and thus more ways of dealing with indestructible than it might appear at first glance (especially to newer players).

Answer (score 23):

No. [Disintegrate](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bDisintegrate%5d) cannot kill [Zetalpa, Primal Dawn](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bZetalpa%2c%20Primal%20Dawn%5d). Creature with indestructible cannot be killed with damage.

Rules quote from comprehensive rules:

> 702.12b A permanent with indestructible can’t be destroyed. Such permanents aren’t destroyed by lethal damage, and they ignore the state-based action that checks for lethal damage (see rule 704.5g).

[Disintegrate](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bDisintegrate%5d) would exile Zetalpa only if Zetalpa would die. In your case Zetalpa won't leave the battlefield.